# Hypothesis testing for more than two samples?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

We do a monthly fundraising letter at my nonprofit. I know how to set up tests in R to compare whether the proportion of response and amount received between two mailings is significantly different, but I would like to compare all twelve for the last year. I figure there is a test to do that, but I don't know what it would be.

Can someone suggest a way to look at 12 samples at once?

Comment: what tests would you do for the comparison of just two?

Comment: I would use a t test to check the donation amounts,and use R's prop.test function to check the response rate (how many responses to the total mailed out). Doing that for each combination would be very repetitive and have some additional error associated with it.

Comment: Yes, it would have the problems you suggest, but it gives me a better idea how to talk about how to do it.

Comment: I think Anova is what I am looking for in a case like this. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance

Comment: *Possibly* you might use ANOVA for amount received, though even there it may not satisfy the assumptions; for example it may well be quite skew. ANOVA is unlikely to be suitable for proportions. There are a number of issues to cover.

Comment: What is the population quantity you want to compare for the amounts? Means? Medians? any reasonable general measure of size? Or are any differences in distribution of interest (e.g. if the means were similar but the standard deviations different, would you care to pick that up?)

Comment: The mailings range from 1000 to 3000 pieces each. I am not at work, so I don't have the means. The response rates are between 2-5% and the mean amounts are somewhere around 70. I'm really just trying to see if there are any 'good' or 'bad' months. I could simply graph the means and response rates on a bar chart and be done with it, but I was trying to do some extra research.

Comment: I'm not asking you to tell me the size of the population, nor the sample sizes nor the means. I am asking 'what aspect of the populations do you want to compare? Would you prefer to compare means or medians or something else, or even to look for distributional differences in general?'

Comment: Ahh, Ultimately, I would like to compare the amounts raised, so I would like to compare the mean and or median donations and the number of donations.